# Change DNA sequences in fasta file using Biopython

Tags: python, biopython, fasta

I have a file in fasta format with several DNA sequences. I want to change the content of each sequence for another smaller sequence, keeping the same sequence id.
The new sequences are in a list.

```
with open("outfile.fa", "w") as f:
    for seq_record in SeqIO.parse("ma-all-mito.fa", "fasta"):
        for i in range(len(newSequences_ok)):
            f.write(str(seq_record.id[i]) + "\n")
            f.write(str(newSequences_ok[i]) + "\n")
```

But I get:

```
IndexError: string index out of range
```

How could I change the code so that it works? I think the problem is that I need to iterate both through the original fasta file and through the list with the new sequences.

The original fasta file looks like this:

```
>Sequence1
ATGATGCATGG
>Sequence2
TTTTGGGAATC
>Sequence3
GGGCTAACTAC
>Sequence4
ATCTCAGGAA
```

And the list with the new sequences is similar to this one:

```
newSequences_ok=[ATGG,TTTC,GGTA,CTCG]
```

The output that I would like to get is:

```
>Sequence1
ATGG
>Sequence2
TTTC
>Sequence3
GGTA
>Sequence4
CTCG
```

Comment: You have questions pending: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39779488

http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Also, what is `newSequences_ok`?

Comment: Please provide more info about your data structure. It would be the easiest if your create a minimal working example (including all `imports` etc) without using BioPyton. btw: Which version of BioPython do you use?

Comment: newSequences_ok is a list with strings of the new sequences of each of the records. It is what I want in the fasta file instead of the previous sequences

Comment: I use Biopython 1.68

Comment: Are you sure that `newSequences_ok` is a list of length 4? Your error seems like it would only happen if it is a *string* of length much greater than 4. Or `seq_record` isn't iterating through strings  like `ATGATGCATGG`

Comment: Even apart from the index-out of range error, I don't see how that nested loop would be expected to produce the output that you want, it seems like you are trying to write the elements of `newSequences_ok` multiple times but your intended output has them appearing once.

Comment: No, it's not of lenght because I have 99 sequences.That was just an example.

Comment: So `SeqIO.parse` returns a list or iterable with elements that alternate between strings like `>Sequence1` and strings like `ATGATGCATGG` and you want to replace every other one with the strings in `newSequences_ok`?

Comment: Yes I think you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this *might* work:

```
records = SeqIO.parse("ma-all-mito.fa", "fasta")
with open("outfile.fa", "w") as f:
    for r, s in zip(records,newSequences_ok):
        f.write(r.seq.seq.split('\n')[0] + '\n')
        f.write(s + '\n')
```

If not (and even if it does) -- you really need to read up on how [Biopython](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html#htoc32) works. You were treating `SeqIO.parse` as something which directly returns the lines of the files. Instead, it returns `SeqRecord` objects which have a `seq` attribute which returns `Seq` objects which themselves have two attributes, a `seq` attribute (which is what you seem to want) and an `alphabet` attribute. You should concentrate on being able to extract the information that you are interested in before you try to modify it.

Comment: It gives this error: TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @newa123 Try it now

Comment: Another error: TypeError: write() argument must be str, not SeqRecord

Comment: @newa123   Then add in `str` again (as in the edit). I wan't sure of the point of that.

Comment: And again: IndexError: list index out of range. Maybe there's a mistake in my previous code

Comment: For debugging purposes, `print(len(records))` followed by `print(records)`. Perhaps it isn't what you think it is. This code (and your question) only makes sense if the length of `records` is twice the length of `newSequences_ok`

Comment: Both the length of records and the length of newSequences_ok is 99.